# Create a list for two models in one ASP.NET Core Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am trying to create a page for a restaurant app I am working on which lists all of the restaurants menus (food/drinks/snacks etc.) and then lists all of the categories below each menu (burgers, pizza, larger, beer etc). This page is in the admin area rather than the customer area and it will allow staff to manage the menus and menu categories.

I have created a razor page which makes a list of all menus, it's displayed on the page using a for each loop - my question is, how would I create a list of all menu categories that are linked to each menu?

For example:

> **Menu 1**
>
> MenuCategory1
> MenuCategory2
> MenuCategory3

> **Menu 2**
>
> MenuCategory1
> MenuCategory2
> MenuCategory3

These are my models:

**Menu.cs**

```
namespace OrderingApp.Models
{
    public class Menu
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**MenuCategory.cs**

```
namespace OrderingApp.Models
{
    public class MenuCategory
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // EF configure foreign keys
        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Menu")]
        public Menu Menu { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my page model and page:

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace OrderingApp.Pages.Admin.ManageMenus
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly OrderingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(OrderingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Menu> Menu { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Menu = await _context.Menus.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model OrderingApp.Pages.Admin.ManageMenus.IndexModel


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Menus";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<hr />

<p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div class="card-deck">

    @foreach (var Menu in Model.Menu)
    {
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px160" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-text"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Menu.Name)</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
               
                        **Another for each loop here for menu categories?
                        <li class="list-group-item">** Each item would go here ** </li>**
                  
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Menu.Id">Edit</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@Menu.Id">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a navigation property to the Menu that represents a collection of MenuCategories:

```
namespace OrderingApp.Models
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<MenuCategory> MenuCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You should use `Include` in the EF query to fetch these:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Menu = await _context.Menus.Include(m => m.MenuCategories).ToListAsync();
}
```

Then you can loop over them:

```
<h2 class="card-text"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Menu.Name)</h2>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
@foreach(var category in Menu.MenuCategories)           
{
    <li class="list-group-item">@categpry.Name</li>**
}              
</ul>
```

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships#navigation-properties

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your detailed answer!